# notify when data changes in parse sdk ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I am calling these to get `all` `user` `list` from `class` `userlist` in  `parse sdk ios`

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"userlist"];
[query orderByAscending:kUserID];

query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        for (PFObject *object in objects)
        {
            NSDictionary *dictUser = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[object valueForKey:kUserName],kUserName,[object valueForKey:kUserID],kUserID,[object valueForKey:kUserImage],kUserImage,nil];
            //NSLog(@"%@",dictUser);
            [mutArrUserList addObject:dictUser];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while getting data");
    }

    //NSLog(@"\nArray - %@",mutArrUserList);
    [tblViewList reloadData];
}];
```

My question is how parse sdk ios can notify when data changes in `class` `userlist`?

Alternate solution is that, i have to continously make call to check by myself that this changes have been done to notify user!!!!!!

Comment: seems very late, but posting a link so everyone looking for it might get a clue. If you want to get an update after user updates anything then you should look into this: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the delegate pattern:

Creating a protocol like this:

```
@protocol myDelegate
@optional -(void)myCustomAction;
@end
```

With a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<myDelegate> delegate;
```

After that you call you delegate method in your completion block, like this:

```
[delegate myCustomAction];
```

Then you need to implement that protocol in another class, just like you do with UITableViewDelegate.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your asking in the parse can notify the app that something is updated on server, than the answer is no. Its your job to go checking for new data. If you dont want to go checking the data to many times then the you add NSDate attribute to parse object and when you want to update data check if the date is old enough to update. And every time you update the date from server also update this date to currenct date.

There is also an option to notify your app via silent push notifications, but that one is not recommended.

Or if your problem is how to get notify about data changes inside ios app, the delegates are the right way. If you'll be more specific about the problem I'll add some more code. Please explain a bit more.